# Use Ivy to manage directories instead of jar files?

Tags: php, dependencies, ivy

Is it possible to use Ivy, or some other dependency-management tool, if your dependencies are directories instead of files?

I'm creating a PHP web site, so my shared "libraries" aren't jar files or any other archive format. I'm aware of .phar files in PHP 5.3, but I really would prefer these to be directories, so the web server can serve their contents directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't depend upon a directory, but you can package your dependencies as a zip, then tell Ivy to unpack them on download. This means when your application is built they will be available locally to the web server.

The [packager](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0-rc1/resolver/packager.html) provides an optional dest attribute that can be specified to unpack the archive to a sub folder. The following config should unpack the dependency to `sub/dir`:

```
<property name="zipname" value="${name}-${version}"/>

<resource dest="sub/dir" url="http://testng.org/${zipname}.zip" 
  sha1="2ea19275dc17453306f8bb780fe6ef6e9af7756b">
    <url href="http://mirror.example.com/archives/${zipname}.zip"/>
    <include name="${zipname}/src/main/**/*"/>
    <include name="${zipname}/src/jdk15/**/*"/>
    <include name="${zipname}/javadocs/**/*"/>
    <include name="${zipname}/*.jar"/>
</resource>
```